# Debugging setup in VB.Net Visual Studio 2019 Community edition

Tags: visual-studio-2019

This is going to sound silly but here it goes.  For quite some time, while debugging in VS 2019, when you hover your mouse over a dictionary(of string, String), you see a little arrow pointing right, when you over over that, the contents would be displayed in array order, showing:

```
(0) Key = "Key", Value = "Value"
(1) Key = "Key", Value = "Value"
(2) Key = "Key", Value = "Value"
```

Now, somehow it's been reversed, it's showing :

```
(0) Value = "Value", Key = "Key"
(1) Value = "Value", Key = "Key"
(2) Value = "Value", Key = "Key"
```

Can someone please point me to where I can set it back to showing the key's first instead of the values?

[image: Screen shot of current display]

Thanks!